# KeyMap Key combination isn't working with Grid, still thinks I'm trying to edit

Tags: javascript, extjs, listener, keydown

I'm trying to add a keyMap to my grid so if you're navigating by arrow keys from row to row you can press 'CTRL + ENTER' to refresh the necessary components. When I use this key combination the grid cell acts like it is being edited instead of refreshing. I think this might be happening because I have a cell editing plugin on the grid as well and since you normally click 'ENTER' to start editing a cell, it is still overriding the 'CTRL+ENTER' KeyMap.

This is how I'm adding the cell editing plugin:

```
defaultConfig.plugins.push({ptype: 'cellediting',clicksToEdit: 2});
```

Here is where I'm adding the KeyMap:

```
addKeyDownListener: function(){
        new Ext.util.KeyMap({
            target: this.getGrid().getEl(),
            binding: [{
                key: Ext.event.Event.ENTER,//Ext.event.Event.F2,//"1",
                ctrl: true,
                alt: false,
                handler: this.listenerKeyDown,
                scope: this
            }]
        }); 
    },
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a simple fiddle demonstrating your problem?